# mongdb pymongo disappearing list of items from collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So I run a local mongodb by running `$ mongod` from the terminal. I then connect to it and create a small database with a python script using `pymongo` :

```
import random
import string
import pymongo

conn            = pymongo.Connection("localhost", 27017)
collection      = conn.db.random_strings 

strings         = numbers = [] 
for i in range(0,1000):
    char_set        = string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits
    num_set         = [ str(num) for num in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] ]
    strings.append( ''.join( random.sample( char_set * 6, 6 ) ) )
    numbers.append( int(''.join( random.sample( num_set * 6, 6 ) ) ) )
    collection.insert( { 'str' : strings[ i ], 'num' : numbers[ i ] } )
```

I now have a database with lots of random strings and numbers in it. Now comes the thing that bugs me and I don't understand:

```
things          = collection.find() 
first_list      = list( things ) 
second_list     = list( things )
print( first_list )
print( second_list )
```

The first print statements returns a list of 1000 objects while the second print statement returns an empty list (`[]`). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
things          = collection.find()
```

actually returns a `Cursor` ([docs](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find)):

> Returns an instance of `Cursor` corresponding to this query.

So, when you create a `list` from the `things` `Cursor`, the entire results from the `find` query are returned and copied into `first_list`. The second time, the `Cursor` instance stored in `things` is at the end of the results, so, there are no more to populate `second_list`.

Comment: is this something thats allowed in python though? the `list()` method returns an object, it doesn't alter the object it is being applied to usually. this is something very specific to the `Cursor` object right?

Comment: The `list` is enumerating the Cursor, which in turn fetches the results from the DB, one by one. It's not a persistent list/result.